# I am having this error Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data while reading object contents

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JSON String that I want to send as a value in a hidden input, I pass the string into the hidden input and call the string in one function that I have created, and I convert the JSON scripting to JavaScript object using JSON.parse inside the function dispay_quality but when I first console.log I get the div

```
<input id="product_qualities" type="hidden" value="[{" product_quality_id":"1","product_quality_name":"novo","status":"1","date_added":"0","product_quality_code":"abg567"},{"product_quality_id":"2","product_quality_name":"usado","status":"1","date_added":"0","product_quality_code":"fcr546"}]"="">
```

however when I console.log the value of the div( console.log n. 2) I get this  only " [{ "
from console log n. 3 I get this error " Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data while reading object contents " I have checked online and says this error appears when wrong JSON is converted.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code;

```
`<script>`
function display_quality(product_id ){

let product_qualities =document.getElementById('product_qualities');
console.log(product_qualities);// console.log n. 1
 product_qualities =product_qualities.value;
console.log(product_qualities);// console log n. 2
product_qualities =JSON.parse(product_qualities);
console.log(product_qualities); console.log n. 3

> }
let product_id = 2;
let require_quality = 1;
let product_qualities_jason = [
   {
      "product_quality_id":"1",
      "product_quality_name":"Novo",
      "status":"1",
      "date_added":"1576671650",
      "product_quality_code":"ABG567"
   },
   {
      "product_quality_id":"2",
      "product_quality_name":"Usado",
      "status":"1","date_added":"1576600000",
      "product_quality_code":"FCR546"
   }
];
product_qualities_jason = JSON.stringify(product_qualities);

let  display = document.getElementById('display');
display.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" id="product_qualities" value="'+product_qualities_jason+'">
> '<b>Select quality</b> '+'<input type="checkbox" id="require_quality" onchange="display_quality('+product_id+')">';
> </script>
HTML-->
> <div id="display"></div>
```

I want to be able to convert from JSON string to JavaScript object

Comment: Change your value to single quotes. So it becomes value="[{' product_quality_id':'1'}]".

Comment: I changed from value="'+product_qualities_jason+'">  to value=\''+product_qualities_jason+'\'> now it works. Thankz